# How to use button reference in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using simple ajax uploader

```
https://github.com/LPology/Simple-Ajax-Uploader
https://www.lpology.com/code/ajaxuploader/docs.php
```

my file upload button

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="button" id="upload-btn1" class="btn btn-success clearfix" value="Choose file">  
</div>
```

I am trying to use onChange callback function of SimpleAjax Uploader

```
onChange( filename, extension, uploadBtn )
```

This Function is called when user selects a file.

The function gets passed three arguments:

- a string containing the filename
- a string containing the file extension
- a reference to the button which triggered the upload

I am facing problem with 3rd parameter of `onChange` function `uploadBtn` which is button reference it can be different digits, so I wonder how can I use this reference to change my upload button text when file is selected!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a bug in simple ajax uploader.

For more info please see [issue #115](https://github.com/LPology/Simple-Ajax-Uploader/pull/115)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the "SimpleAjax Uploader" library, but typical jQuery callbacks return a DOM element, rather than a wrapped set. Therefore, you should be able to change the displayed text of the button by converting it to a jQuery wrapped set and using the `val()` method. In the sample below, `uploadBtn` is a DOM element. The anchor tag's `click` handler wraps it and uses `val()` to change the text after each click.

```js
var uploadBtn = document.getElementById('uploadBtn');

$('a').click(function() {
  var d = new Date();
  $(uploadBtn).val("Changed at " + d);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="uploadBtn" type="button" value="Default text" />
<br/>
<a href="#">Change the text of the button</a>
```

In your case, you'd have an `onchange` callback like:

```
function onchange( filename, extension, uploadBtn ) {
  $(uploadBtn).val("New text goes here");
}
```

Comment: thanks , i can change button value on click , but what if use click button and not selected any file ! , so am stuck with that library onChange function , but its 3rd parameters is confusing me !

Comment: My code is an example of how to reference an incoming parameter. I'll expand my answer to make the parallel more clear.

Comment: $(uploadBtn).val("New text goes here");            i tried that already it not work .     uploadBTn   reference return digits like 22   183 etc

Comment: It doesn't sound like the `uploadBtn` parameter is actually referring to a button. You'll have to investigate your API more closely, possibly including reading the source code if you can't contact its maintainer.

Comment: ya i submitted issue to their developers